# How to Write Twitter Push Notification

Tags: android, twitter

I have developed a Twitter application, it enter onto twitter page, but i need to push notification when i click the check box button.
i also used a "twitter4j-core-2.1 jar" file also.

If any one know please help me with a sample code.

Thank you in advanced.